# Windows RDP freeze

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, freeze, monitoring

I'm working on server using RDP (remote desktop).
Since some weeks i notice that i have frequent screenfreezes (up to 2seconds).

I'm programming on the server and from time to time there is no response.
After the 2second freeze -> the text is comming on the screen.
Also when i'm drawing or using other programs like excel etc.

When i restart the server, the problem is solved for some weeks.
I don't think its an network issue (but i keep it open as a possiblity)

Server OS: Windows 2012R2

The server is standing at another location and we use vpn.
I know this can be a bottle neck and can be the reason of the delays and screenfreezes.

If i see in Taskmanager cpu, ram, disk,... i don't see anything unnormal.

The question:
How can i trace the reason of the screenfreezes ?
I want to solve my issue by finding the reason (also an interesting thing to know how to... solve issues).

If you have question's or things that you want to know, let me know down below and i will answer them asap.

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: It might be worth having a constant ping network test running from your client to the server and see if any outages/spikes/timeouts show up at the same time as the freeze.  This might then at least indicate that networking is related.  PsPing (Sysinternals), Test-Connection (PowerShell) or regular ping could be useful.